# Entity Framework for multi-form winforms desktop app

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, design-patterns, architectural-patterns

I am developing desktop app based on winforms and EF.

At the moment I have some problems with EF and architecture:

1. Syncronizing data. There are multiple forms and each form uses it's own instance of database context. When data is updated on one form I need manually update it on other forms. There are a lot of non-flexible callbacks and copy-paste that refresh data.
2. There are some calculations that running on client side and update a lot of records. Sometime user need to save it and with EF it takes a long time. So, it is also running in separate Context so that work with other entities is not blocked
3. There are DataGridViews with Binding entities and there are annoyingproblems with `DbSet<T>.Local` and `DbSet<T>.ToList()`. When data in gridview is saved it is sometimes is not updated in other places.

I am looking for any best practices and flexible patterns that can be used there. Also, looking forward to hear from those who solved same problems.

Thanks

Comment: Remember you should be creating a new `DbContext` instance with each operation: do not keep them open with UI elements. EF is designed around the Unit of Work pattern.

Comment: One question per post please! And show the *code* in which you have problems. We can't do anything with vague descriptions like "lot of non-flexible callbacks", "sometimes is not updated", etc. etc.

Comment: @HighCore I don't think WPF or MVVM actually solve any of the problems mentioned in the question (synchronization between different contexts, binding to local set, blocking long running tasks when updating lots of records, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done in the past (by no means "best practices", but it has worked for me, so here it goes):

1. Use a kind of "visitor pattern". Have a class where your forms (or presenters, or whatever pattern you use) subscribe indicating they want to be notified of changes. Then on your `SaveChanges()` you go along the `ChangeSet` and notify those parties that have requested it. I have optimized this by forms/presenters only subscribing to changes on certain types, and I give it to them in a batch. Each form does whatever they want with that data (refresh the current entity from the store, check the entities that are displayed on a grid, etc.).

   **Also**, I have a `DateTime` member (which gets popullated automatically on `SaveChanges`) on each record and a special table with records for each of the main editable collections of records (think globally, "Customers", "Invoices", etc.) which has a `DateTime` of the last time those records where updated. I can poll that with a timer if needed (I use that for inter-app communication, not for communicating between forms within the current app).
2. Depending on your needs, doing all that changes on a thread might work for you. You may want to set soft-locks (where you control them in-app, disabling the `Save` button, or the editability of a grid, or whatever) if your calculations really take a long time (or set concurrency checks on `SaveChanges`) so that the user can't save a record that is being modified on that thread, but then again, that's up to your UI/UX preferences or requirements.
3. I don't bind directly to the `DbSet` (much less `Local` if you are working with several contexts), I have a collection that I bind to. The "data not updated in other places" should be solved by point 1

Again, I'm not saying this is the "best" or "recommended" way, but I have used it and, for me, it has worked just fine. Your mileage may vary.

PS: not official or anything, but this link may be an interesting read for managing the lifetime of your `DbContext` (which may be or may be not a bit off the original question): http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/ (disclaimer: I don't use his "dbcontextscopes", and just point this link for the text read, I don't know whether his code will be good or not)